# awk -cut how to delete second column with field separator

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file with data presented as follows

```
'&(||o||022344527||o||lonyfoe||o||Joe||o||Joe||o||Otieno
```

I'm trying to delete second column.

Output :

```
'&(||o||lonyfoe||o||Joe||o||Joe||o||Otieno
```

Any ideas?

This is what I have tried so far

```
cut -d'||o||' -f2 --complement 

awk -F'||o||' '{
   for(n=1; n<=NF; n++){
      if(n!=NF)fmt="%s|"; else fmt="%s\n"
      if(n!=2)printf(fmt,$n)
   }
}'
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: I know language evolves, but I feel like it's really a stretch to call that a "Comma-Separated Values" file :-/

Comment: That is not a CSV by any definition of the term, even if you stretch the "CS" to mean Character Separated instead of Comma Separated the values are separated by multi-character strings, not by individual characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you on same:

```
awk '{sub(/\|\|o\|\|[0-9]+\|\|o\|\|/,"||o||")} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
'&(||o||lonyfoe||o||Joe||o||Joe||o||Otieno
```

Answer (score 2):

`cut` delimiters can only be a single character. In you case you can use `|`, so that each value separated by `||o||` is considered as 4 fields (empty, `o`, empty, value). The second column is now the 5-8 range :

```
 cut -d'|' -f5-8 --complement
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following...

```
sed -e 's/||o||/|/g' your-input-file | cut -d'|' -f1,3- | sed -e 's/|/||o||/g'
```

- The first sed command converts the original delimiter into a single '|' that will work better with the cut command.  The cut command seems to want only single character delimiters.
- The cut command strips out the second field leaving the rest.  The '-f1,3-' is used as it might be more compatible with more versions of 'cut'.  The "--complement" option may not be available on all versions of the cut command. Eg. on Mac OSX.
- the final sed command just reverses the delimiter back to the original value

hope that helps.

Comment: good one, but this assumes that no other field contains the character `|`... for formatting the code, select that line and press `ctrl+k` or click the `{}` icon

Comment: Thanks for the tip on code formatting. Done. Yes, you are correct on the assumption that the fields do not contain "|" characters, that is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

added sample line with non-numeric second field

```
$ cat ip.txt
'&(||o||022344527||o||lonyfoe||o||Joe||o||Joe||o||Otieno
ijk||o||foobar||o||123||o||xyz
```

solution using `perl`

```
$ perl -lne '$,="||o||"; @f=split /\Q$,/; print @f[0,2..$#f]' ip.txt
'&(||o||lonyfoe||o||Joe||o||Joe||o||Otieno
ijk||o||123||o||xyz
```

- `$,="||o||"` sets the separator used between `print`'s arguments
- `@f=split /\Q$,/` get array with separator specified by `$,` where `\Q` is useful to escape regex meta characters. By default, `split` will act upon `$_` - input record in this case
- `print @f[0,2..$#f]` print required fields, value of `$,` determines the string used between array elements

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/||o||/\n/g;s/[^\n]*\n//2;s/\n/||o||/g' file
```

Replace all delimiters by newlines. Remove the second field and its delimiter. Replace newlines by delimiters.

An alternative:

```
sed 's/||o||/\n/2;s/\(.*||o||\).*\n/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed 's/\(||o||[^|]*\)//1' infile
```