# Using multiple character string as separator in awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file in which records are of the following format:

A||o||BCD||o||E||o||XYZ

I want to use '||o||' as the separator to get my records:

But When I use:

```
awk -F'||o||' '{print $1}'
```

I am getting the following error:

> awk: illegal primary in regular expression ||o|| at |o||

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828159/awk-cut-how-to-delete-second-column-with-field-separator ... same delimiter ;)

Comment: I don't get error with GNU awk.. so suggestion to add awk version to your question

Comment: Where are these files that use `||o||` as a separator coming from??? I keep seeing them mentioned in this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to escape literal pipes in a regular expression

`awk -F'[|][|]o[|][|]' '{print $1}'`

or

`awk -F'[|]{2,2}o[|]{2,2}' '{print $1}'`

The usual backslash escape is different in awk, so to use it (at least on GNU bash, version 4.3.42)

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\|\\|o\\|\\|"} {print $1}' pipe.txt`

and also this ugly syntax using the `-F` option

`awk -F "\\\|\\\|o\\\|\\\|" '{print $1}' pipe.txt`

The double escapes are well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072825).

Comment: Luis, on my system, `awk -F'\|\|o\|\|' '{print $1}'` doesn't work, but the `awk -F'[|][|]o[|][|]' '{print $1}'` and the `awk -F'[|]{2,2}o[|]{2,2}' '{print $1}'` do. If you take the first away, I will upvote your solution.

Comment: @Luis Muñoz: I took the freedom to remove your first solution which is not working, but I left the second and the third one.

Comment: Thx a lot. I added more info about that at the end of the answer.

Comment: @Luis Muñoz: Ha sido un placer.