# Find strings lefted between 2 text files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i'm using this command bellow to check lefted not found strings on 2 files,

by checking the first column on each text file string.

Separator is : ||o||

```
awk -F '||o||' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)'

example : foo||o||boo||o||bar||o||baz||o||pat||o||mat
```

Its work only for 1st column.

I want to add 6 column if possible...

i will be grateful if you help me

Comment: OK, seriously - what is generating these files that use `||o||` as a field separator? This is at least the 3rd question we've had about them in the past couple of weeks and they're not all coming from the same account. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48931749/1745001

Comment: norm-of-o https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics) :)

Answer (score 2):

your field separator is not correctly set, you have to double escape the pipe char.

```
$ awk -F '\\|\\|o\\|\\|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$6]; next} !(($1,$6) in a)' file1 file2
```

will check the combination of first and sixth field.

Of course since you don't have a testable input/output it's impossible to be sure that I understood the question correctly.