# Awk command to extract columns on dual delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, cut

I have a file which contains rows like this

```
name[^legalName[^code[^type[^contactNumber1[^contactNumber2
```

I want to extract column two from this file. I don't find any problem when I have a single character delimiter. But how do I extract when there is a multiple character delimiter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple character string as separator in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931749/using-multiple-character-string-as-separator-in-awk)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` interprets the field separator as a regular expression, so you just need to double `\\` escape each character to get the literals.

```
echo 'name[^legalName[^code[^type[^contactNumber1[^contactNumber2' | awk -F'\\[\\^' '{print $2}'
legalName
```